# R library(RCurl) behavior change on travis-ci

Tags: r, ubuntu, travis-ci, libcurl, rcurl

this line of code previously worked on travis-ci but now fails.  works fine on appveyor

```
RCurl::getURL( "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/" , ftp.use.epsv = TRUE, dirlistonly = TRUE )
```

here's the text of the error-

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  server did not report OK, got 425
Calls: get_catalog ... <Anonymous> -> curlPerform -> .Call -> <Anonymous> -> fun
```

i think my `.travis.yml` is a pretty standard r configuration:

```
language: r
cache: packages
sudo: required
apt_packages:
- unixodbc-dev
- libarchive-dev
```

successful build log late february 2018 at https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/343635739/log.txt

failed build log early march 2018 https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/352115990/log.txt

the libcurl block looks nearly identical, but there's one noticeable difference between the success and the failure--

late feburary success:

```
2 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 1 to remove and 124 not upgraded.
```

mid march failure:

```
2 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 1 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
```

minor r session info changes:

late february success:

```
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------
 date     2018-02-20                  
 DBI            0.7        2017-06-18 cran (@0.7)                       
 devtools       1.13.4     2017-11-09 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
 lodown         0.1.0      2018-02-20 Github (ajdamico/lodown@6a69363)  
 rlang          0.1.6      2017-12-21 cran (@0.1.6)                     
 srvyr          0.3.0      2018-01-24 cran (@0.3.0)
```

mid march failure:

```
 Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------
 date     2018-03-12                  
 DBI            0.8        2018-03-02 cran (@0.8)                       
 devtools       1.13.5     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
 lodown         0.1.0      2018-03-12 Github (ajdamico/lodown@bef726b)  
 rlang          0.2.0      2018-02-20 cran (@0.2.0)                     
 srvyr          0.3.1      2018-03-10 cran (@0.3.1)
```

Comment: i think i've narrowed down the root cause (but not resolution) here--  https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9352